# Can I tap in to a interior wall outlet for outside

Tags: electrical

I want to tap in into a wall outlet that I don’t use and add a outside outside. I’m using it for a electric grill that requires 110 volt, 60hz, 275w, 5 amp service but I don’t know if I will overload it. What should I do before?

Comment: you should find out what else is on that circuit.  switch off the breaker and inventory what has no power.

Answer (score 3):

Yes But keep in mind that the outside outlet must be GFCI protected.

If the inside outlet is not GFCI protected already you can replace that inside outlet with a GFCI outlet and attach the outside outlet to the load terminals of the GFCI.

To prevent overloads you can do a check for what else is on that circuit and add all the Watts together and divide by 110. This will give you a worst case current draw. If that is less than 90% of the rating of the breaker there is no issue of overload.

Comment: Yes, don't remove the inside receptacle because *you* don't use it. A receptacle there may be required by code, and might be used by someone later.  Put the GFCI receptacle inside to protect it from weathering. Feed a standard receptacle outside using the load contacts of the GFCI receptacle.